# Python: What's the difference between set.difference and set.difference_update?

Tags: python, set, difference

**s.difference(t)** returns a new set with no elements in **t**.

**s.difference_update(t)** returns an updated set with no elements in **t**.

What's the difference between these two set methods?
Because the difference_update updates set s, what precautions should be taken to avoid receiving a result of None from this method?

In terms of speed, shouldn't set.difference_update be faster since you're only removing elements from set s instead of creating a new set like in set.difference()?

Comment: Regarding the terminology: `s.difference_update(t)` doesn't **return** an updated set. It updates the set. This is an instruction, not an expression.

Comment: `difference_update` doesn't return anything, so it will always be `None` if you take the return value. If everything is removed you will have `s` as an empty `set`.

Comment: @Aristide: regarding the terminology, `s.difference_update(t)` *does* return something - the `None` object -, and it *is* an expression. Python's instructions are `import`, `def`, `class`, `for`, `while`, `with`, `break`, `continue`, `return`, `yield`, `try`, `except`, `finally`, `raise` and the assignment operator `=` (I probably forgot a couple but well, you get the idea).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, you're right. I should have used the term "statement" instead of "instruction" (in french, my native language, "instruction" is used with both meanings). I'm aware that Python's statements have a None value (instead of having no value). My point was: "In most languages, statements contrast with expressions in that statements do not return results and are executed solely for their side effects, while expressions always return a result and often do not have side effects at all." (Wikipedia).

Comment: @Aristide: `s.difference_update(t)` is still an expression-  something that has a value which can be bound to a name. You can write `result=s.difference_update(t)` so it is an expression. And being French too, I used the term "instruction" as a synonym of "statement". I do understand the point you're trying to make and from a semantical POV `set.difference_update` is indeed used for side-effect and not it's return value, but technically it's still an expression. Python's statement don't "have a `None` value", they don't have any value at all, since trying to use them as RHS is a syntax error.

Answer (score 13):

**Q.** What's the difference between these two set methods?

**A.** The *update* version subtracts from an existing set, mutating it, and potentially leaving it smaller than it originally was.  The *non-update* version produces a new set, leaving the originals unchanged.

**Q.** Because the difference_update updates set s, what precautions should be taken to avoid receiving a result of None from this method?

**A.** Mutating methods in Python generally return *None* as a way to indicate that they have mutated an object.  The only "precaution" is to not assign the *None* result to a variable.

**Q.** In terms of speed, shouldn't set.difference_update be faster since you're only removing elements from set s instead of creating a new set like in set.difference()?

**A.** Yes, the algorithm of the *update* version simply discards values.

In contrast, the algorithm for the non-updating version depends on the size of the sets.

If the size of *s* is four or more times larger that *t*, the new set version first copies the main set and then discards values from it.  So `"s - t` is implemented as `n = s.copy(); n.difference_update(t)`).  That algorithm is used when *s* is much larger than *t*

Otherwise, the algorithm for the non-updating version is to create an empty new set *n*, loop over the elements of *s* and add them to *n* if they are not present in *t*.

Answer (score 12):

`difference_update` updates the set in place rather than create a new one.

```
>>> s={1,2,3,4,5}
>>> t={3,5}
>>> s.difference(t)
{1, 2, 4}
>>> s
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> s.difference_update(t)
>>> s
{1, 2, 4}
```