# Common lists in 2 python lists of lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of lists in python, as follows:

```
a = [['1490526293.84', '2010113827', 'amazon.com', '208.67.220.220'],
     ['1490526293.78', '2010113827', 'amazon.com', '208.67.222.222'],
     ['1490525901.72', '2010113827', 'amazon.com', '8.8.4.4'],
     ['1490526293.66', '2010113827', 'amazon.com', '8.8.8.8'],
     ['1490525291.24', '151249113', 'google.com', '208.67.220.220'],
     ['1490524291.18', '151249113', 'google.com', '208.67.222.222'],
     ['1490526289.02', '151249113', 'google.com', '8.8.4.4'],
     ['1490526288.96', '151249113', 'google.com', '8.8.8.8'],
     ['1490525291.46', '2017032579', 'intuit.com', '208.67.220.220'],
     ['1490526291.41', '2017032579', 'intuit.com', '208.67.222.222'],
     ['1490526291.35', '2017032579', 'intuit.com', '8.8.4.4'],
     ['1490526291.29', '2017032579', 'intuit.com', '8.8.8.8']]

b = [['1490526293.66', '2010113827', 'amazon.com', '8.8.8.8'],
     ['1490526288.96', '151249113', 'google.com', '8.8.8.8'],
     ['1490526291.29', '2017032579', 'intuit.com', '8.8.8.8']]
```

For each item in the lists:

- item 0 is epoch_time
- item 1 is serial_number
- item 2 is domain_name
- item 3 is DNS_server

The initial requirement was to find every list in **a** not present in **b**. This was simple enough and was done as follows:

```
for item in a:
    if item not in b:
        print item
```

However, now I need to find lists in **a** that do not appear in **b**, and also have an epoch time difference of more than 5 minutes for a particular domain from the list in **b**, so that the output is as follows:

```
[['1490525901.72', '2010113827', 'amazon.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490525291.24', '151249113', 'google.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490524291.18', '151249113', 'google.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490525291.46', '2017032579', 'intuit.com', '208.67.220.220']]
```

What I have tried so far is as follows:

```
for item_a in a:
    if item_a not in b:
        for item_b in b:
            if item_a[2] == item_b[2]:
                if float(item_b[0]) - float(item_a[0]) > 300:
                    print item_a
```

This is crazily nested and I was looking for better alternatives

Comment: The question is not clear enough for me. Can you remove all information that is not related to the question?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder..edited it..let me know if it clearer..

Comment: Also..why the downvote..how is this too broad..I gave the exact problem statement..gave code for what I have tried out..and asking for a very specific answer..

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'm guessing that the reason would most likely be because your question is about how to write a particular piece of code that you did not show your attempt for. In your question you showed how you solved part 'a' of your problem. But part 'b' is an entirely different question that you have not showed any code for. Have you tried solving that part of the question? If so, then provide that code and explain what difficulties you are having.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can do it with nested if statements like you did previously, for each list in a check whether or not it appears in b; if it doesn't then check if the epoch time is within 5 minutes of any of the epoch times appearing in b (which you could do by for looping through all of b).

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to solve your problem, but the time complexity may be high.

```
for item_a in a:
  if item_a not in b:
     for item_b in b:
         if item_a[2]==item_b[2]:
             if abs(float(item_a[0])-float(item_b[0]))>5*60:
                 print item_a
                 break
```

if the item from list a (item_a) and item form list b (item_b) have same domain_name  and the absolute value of the difference between item_a[0] and item_b[0] more than 5*60 ,print the item_a.

Comment: @bestbzw..this is quite similar to my attempt..I was looking for solutions which are a bit less nested..

Answer (score -1):

For some reason I could not just comment, so I will write it here.

Since your sublists are unique, maybe you could try-out with one of these set operators.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27439300